# jsp tag foreach var is not recognized

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I am trying to display a list of customer inside a jsp page selected from a service as follows 
entity :

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long idClient;

    private String nom;

    private String prenom;

    private String adress;

    private String mail;
```

service:

```
    @Autowired
    private IClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping(value= "/")
    public String clients(Model model){

        List<Client> clients = clientService.selectAll();

        if(clients == null) { clients = new ArrayList<Client>(); };

        System.out.println("client size = "+clients.size());//debug : contains 2 elements 

        model.addAttribute("clients", clients);

        return "client/clients";
    }
}
```

my jsp page : 
tag lib :

```
< %@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

and the jsp code used to display the customers

```
<c:forEach  items="${clients}" var="client">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${client.getNom()}</td>
                                    <td> ${client.prenom}<</td>
                                    <td> ${client.adress}<</td>
                                    <td> ${client.mail }<</td>
                                    <td><a href="">Edit</a>, <a href="">delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
< /c:forEach>
```

but the client fields are not recognized 
here is the error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/client/clients.jsp at line 85

82:                         <tbody>
83:                              <c:forEach  items="${clients}" var="client">
84:                                 <tr>
85:                                     <td>${client.nom }</td>
86:                                     <td> ${client.prenom }<</td>
87:                                     <td> ${client.adress }<</td>
88:                                     <td> ${client.mail }<</td>


javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'nom' not found on type java.lang.String
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:268)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:355)
```

Comment: are you sure the class `Client` has a property called `nom`? can you add the class `Client` to your question?

Comment: entity with with getters and setters but to avoid extra lines of code I ommited them in the comment

Comment: there is an extra space in `items="${clients }"` - what happens if you remove it?

Comment: I keep getting the same error even if I fix items and change the tag to       <td>${client.getNom()}</td> (using the getter)

Comment: just to double check, in the service, do you return the model to the JSP (i.e. something like `ModelAndView`)? can you provide more context about how the service exits and invokes the JSP?

Comment: there is also a space here `< %@ taglib uri="...">` you will need to remove the space between the `<` and the `%`

Comment: for the controller method, when debugging the list clients contains two elements (selected from database) and returned to the view using the model.addAttribute
for the tag lib, it cannot be displayed in the comment above thats why I added the extra space

Comment: It all seems to be aligned correctly... not sure what's going on?  Are you sure this JSP is `client/clients.jsp` ? you do not have a duplicate JSP somewhere else?

Comment: yes it is, in addition, this is the first table I am creating in this app

Comment: I tried also two types of uri : "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" and "http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" (for this one there is another error about tld not defining any expression for items) !

Comment: I tried to loop over the list of clients and i found that it displays a single line while it is supposed to have two rows

Comment: the content of clients is /mvc/clients/ which corresponds to the link of the page ! any idea how to fix this ??

Comment: solved by changing the model attribute variable from clients to elements or any other variable name !! probably because of the request mapping having the same value (clients)

Comment: ah, I see... I did not think of that... weird.